# Implementing flick or smooth ( or kinetic ) scrolling in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

I need something like ListBox scrolling in iPhone OS (iOS).

How can you implement flick/smooth/kinetic scrolling in Silverlight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPhone like scrolling on Silverlight ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817441/iphone-like-scrolling-on-silverlight-listbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post from Sacha Barber's website:

http://sachabarber.net/?p=481

Jeremiah Morrill shares code that implements animated scrolling with inertia in a custom ContentControl (templated with an included ScrollViewer)